# All squares above 6 have an even number of multiples of 10. Why?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, puzzle

I was recently looking at a puzzle in Martin Gardner's book:

> Two brothers sell their heard of sheep, and receive the same number of
>   dollars per sheep, as there were sheep in the heard. They receive the
>   money in $\$10$ bills, and then the remainder is made up of silver
>   dollars.
>
> They split the money by alternating taking \$10 bills, and then the
>   last takes all the silver dollars. The older brother goes first, and
>   takes the first bill, and the last bill - so the younger brother
>   complains that he receives less.
>
> The older brother agrees to write him a cheque to cover the
>   difference. How much is the cheque for?

Now, to get to the solution - as the book says - you know that the total amount of money was $\$n^2$, and that $n^2 - n^2 \mod 10$ is odd. Looking at the squares, you have $1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,\ldots$ . And so the number of sheep has to have been either 4, or 6, and so the cheque must be for $\$2$. But how do I show that all the squares above 6 have an even number of tens?

Pointed out below, were $14^2, 16^2, 24^2, 26^2, \ldots$ - all the squares of numbers ending in 4 or 6. Is there a relationship with these numbers?

Comment: They don't. Look at $14^2, 16^2, 24^2,...$

Comment: Yah okay, looks like the answer in the book is sort of wrong. It's still correct, but the logic is wrong - i'll adjust the question.

Comment: Every number has the form $10n, 10n+1, \dots, 10n+9$ for some $n$. Check out all the possibilities.

Comment: @JohnBrevik Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All integers are of the form $10n\pm k$, where $0\le k\le5$. Squaring, we have $100n^2\pm20kn+k^2$. 
 For $k^2<10\iff0\le k\le3$, the tens digit is always even. For $k=4$ we have numbers ending 
 in $4$ and $10-4=6$ yielding squares with an odd tens digit, since $4^2={\color{red}1}6$. For $k=5$ we have 
 $k^2={\color{red}2}5$, so the tens digit is again even.

Answer (score 0):

The number of sheep is $10x+y$ , with  $0 \le x$ and  $0 \le y \le 9$ . The money total is $(10x+y)^2=100x^2+20xy +y^2 = 10(10.x^2 +2y) +y^2$.  Now the  even number $10.x^2 +2xy$  cannot be the number of bills, which is odd, so $y^2$  must equal  $10A+B$ where $A$ is odd and $0 \le B \le 9$. But since $y^2 \in \{ 0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81 \}$  ,  we must have $y^2 \in \{ 16,36 \}$ . So there are 6 silver dollars and the cheque is for 2 dollars.

Comment: Was about to give you the award. The cheque is for $\$2$! you have to half it to make it fair :/

Comment: 2 bucks,yeah ok .i stopped thinking.  if it was a lot of money i would have kept thinking

Comment: The book it's from even mentions later "the number of people who solve the difficult part and then go on to forget the divide by 2 is staggering" (or something along those lines)